# How should I return to a previous dialog from another one?

Tags: java, android

I've got an `inputDialog`, which allows for some text inputs. On clicking save, the `inputDialog` checks if the entered text is already available (to prevent double entries). If this is the case, a new `AlertDialog` is created, simply stating "The value you entered already exists", with just an "Ok" button to dismiss this `AlertDialog`. This all works.

I would like to have the `inputDialog` pop back up again, after dismissing the `AlertDialog`, with the values that were entered by the user before still in the `editText` fields.

I'm not expecting any problems on getting those values back in the `editText` fields (Store them in a variable on clicking save, if the double entry error occurs, set those variables on the `editText`'s. If I'm doing this in a stupid way, please let me know).

I am however having trouble with getting the first (`inputDialog`) dialog to come back. The code you see below is the code for my `inputDialog` fragment (The code is simplified, so if something seems to be missing, it probably is. Let me know, so I can add it back in.)

So, to repeat myself: How can I return to the previous dialog after dismissing the second one?

**StuffManagerInputDialogFragment.java:**

```
public class StuffManagerInputDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    EditText nameInputField;
    EditText tagInputField;
    DBHandler dbHandler;
    StuffManagerFragment f = new StuffManagerFragment();

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View v_iew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inputdialog, null);

        nameInputField = (EditText) v_iew.findViewById(R.id.inputdialogname);
        tagInputField = (EditText) v_iew.findViewById(R.id.inputdialogtag);
        dbHandler = new DBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);
        final MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        final AlertDialog.Builder newLinkDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        newLinkDialog.setView(v_iew)
                .setTitle("New Link")
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String nameInputFieldText = nameInputField.getText().toString();
                        String tagInputFieldText = tagInputField.getText().toString();
                        ArrayList<String> nameArray = dbHandler.nameArrayMethod();
                        ArrayList<String> tagArray = dbHandler.tagArrayMethod();
                        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                        Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

                        if (nameArray.contains(nameInputFieldText) || tagArray.contains(tagInputFieldText)) {
                            if (nameArray.contains(nameInputFieldText) && tagArray.contains(tagInputFieldText)) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder errorBoth = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                        .setTitle("Error")
                                        .setMessage("The name and tag you entered are already in use.")
                                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black)
                                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                //Return to previous dialog here
                                            }
                                        });
                                        errorBoth.show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            dbHandler.addLink(nameInputFieldText, tagInputFieldText);
                            nameArray = dbHandler.nameArrayMethod();

                            int nameArraySize = (nameArray.size() - 1);
                            MenuItem item = menu.add(R.id.group1, nameArraySize, 1, nameArray.get(nameArraySize));

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "'" + nameInputFieldText + " - " + tagInputFieldText + "' link saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            ma.addSMVFFragments();
                            f.hideDeleteAllButton = false;
                            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        return newLinkDialog.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What value would I have to save/retrieve? Are you talking about the text in the `editText` fields, or about the dialog itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to have a dialog fragment for your input layout, and that dialog fragment would display an AlertDialog on OK if the text validation fails. The input dialog fragment would not dismiss in this case, it will remain in the background so when you dismiss the alert dialog to tell the user the input is invalid, you return to the input dialog as it was.

To prevent the dialog fragment from dismissing on OK you would override onStart and get a reference to the OK button and set the listener there, like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
    if (alertDialog != null) {
        mOKButton = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        mOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (field OK) {
                    // save data
                    dismiss();
                } else {
                    // show error dialog
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you describe the `AlertDialog` popping up without dismissing the `inputDialog` is an even better solution.  
However, I think I should have said that the `inputDialog` is actually a dialog fragment.  
To prevent the dialog fragment from dismissing, you said I should override onStart. Where should I do this?

Comment: Right, so if your input dialog is already a dialog fragment then there isn't a whole lot you need to change, just get the OK button handler in onStart and dismiss only if the data is valid.
By default an alert dialog will dismiss when you click on any button, so setting the click listener in onStart will allow you to override that and dismiss only when you want to, by calling dismiss().

Comment: So if I get this correctly, I should get the button handler for the OK button (button that dismisses the double entries error)? Where would I have onStart? In the dialog fragment?

Comment: The onStart is for the Dialog Fragment, and the OK button is the button for the input dialog that lets the user save the data. In the click listener for this button you check if the value already exists - if it does, you show an alert dialog. If it doesn't, you save the data and call dismiss() to dismiss the dialog fragment.

Comment: It took me a while to understand everything, but it works exactly as intended. Thank you sir!